# MySQL loop to create multiple tables and insert data from local CSV file

Tags: mysql

I have created an empty table A in MySQL and inserted data from a local csv file, A.csv, using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. Now I want to create more tables just like A and insert data from other different local csv files (they all have the same fields).

So for table B it will be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE B LIKE A;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'mypath/B.csv'
...
```

I need to repeat this process for about 20 tables. How can I write a loop procedure to automate the process?

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you going to be doing this many time?

Comment: Create stored procedure, use dynamic SQL. But if this is one-time or rare task then it is more easy to do this "by hands".